# Register Generic Type using lambda expression with a parameter in AutoFac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I am trying to do [this](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html#parameters-with-lambda-expression-components) but with a generic class like:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        public BaseRepository(IIndex<ContextKey, IDbContextBase> factory, ContextKey key)
        {
            Context = factory[key];
            Set = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
}
```

So that I could pass the `ContextKey` key as a parameter.

I am trying to dynamically resolve a dbcontext based on what key has been passed to ctor of the `BaseRepository<>` class.

**Register** it like this:

```
builder.Register((c, p) =>
                 new BaseRepository<>(p.Named<ContextKey>("key")))
       .As<IBaseRepository<>>();
```

**Resolve** like:

```
var reader = scope.Resolve<IBaseRepository<ActionEntity>>(
new NamedParameter("key", ContextKey.Applications));
```

The Key being passed is:

```
public enum ContextKey
{
    Pure, Phoebus, Applications, Legacy, None
}
```

and the `factory` parameter is built into Autofac - its auto injected and handled by Autofac.

Comment: Going to need some clarification on the key and factory delegate. where is the key coming from and how does it change in relation to resolving the dependency via the factory. It looks like implementation concern that can be delegated to the composition root.

Answer (score 2):

Having `IIndex<ContextKey, IDbContextBase> factory, ContextKey key` in the repository constructor looks a lot like  implementation concerns that can be delegated to the composition root.

I would first simplify the constructor of the repository to follow explicit dependency principle.

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : class, new() {

    //...

    public BaseRepository(IDbContextBase context) {
        Context = context;
        Set = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    //...
}
```

The Composition Root can will then be responsible to making sure the repository is constructed correctly.

```
ContextKey key = //known value

//...Assumes IIndex<ContextKey, IDbContextBase> factory is registered

builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(IBaseRepository<>))
    .WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDbContextBase) && pi.Name == "context",
            (pi, ctx) => {
                var factory = ctx.Resolve<IIndex<ContextKey, IDbContextBase>>();
                return factory[key];
            })
    );

//...

var container = builder.Build();
```

Note the use of the `ResolvedParameter` to dynamically get the parameter to be injected into the repository.

Comment: Not a bad idea but i want to be pass different `ContextKey` into the ctor so this statement `return factory[key]` would return a different implementation of `IDbContextBase` - which at present stands at 4.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz And how do you determine which key to use?

Comment: So i was thinking something crazy like:

`public class ActionsRepository : BaseRepository<ActionEntity>`

AND the ctor: `public ActionRepository(IIndex<ContextKey, IDbContextBase> factory, ContextKey key) : base(factory[key])`

Comment: I can also chuck in the towel and dont bother trying to test my `BaseRepository<TEntity>` registration and just concentrate on derived repos instead. 

So just do this instead and call it day:

`public class ActionsRepository : BaseRepository<ActionEntity>` AND the ctor: `public ActionRepository(IApplicationDbContext ctx) : base(ctx)`